# What do s, m, w, m-w, and w-s mean in the context of infrared spectroscopy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

I am referring to Donald Pavia's *Introduction to Spectroscopy*, and I found this table that tells about the intensities of the peaks of vibrations of certain bonds.

[image]

I can't understand what `s`, `m`, `w`, `w-s`, etc. are supposed to mean. My guess is that `s` could mean small, `m` could mean medium and `w` could mean weak. But that's crazy, since small and weak mean the same thing? So what do they mean actually?

Comment: I'm quite sure this is described in the book itself.

Comment: @Mithoron Unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: @Mithoron how is ft-ir an appropriate tag for this? My question has nothing to do with Fourier transform spectroscopic technique, it's just regular infrared.

Comment: This is the tag for IR spectroscopy, ft is standard procedure.

Comment: @hBy2Py is correct. I have found a similar table on another page which is a bit more explicit in what its abbreviations mean and every thing lines up with the the notation of  **s**trong/ **m**edium/ **w**eak. https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/Spectrpy/InfraRed/infrared.htm

Comment: It is described in the book, p 28 (5th ed) *"Often, when reading the literature of organic chemistry, you will find absorptions referred to as strong (s), medium (m), weak (w), broad, or sharp."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the general agreement surrounding [my comment on the question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76907/what-does-s-m-w-m-w-w-s-mean-in-the-context-of-infrared-spectroscopy?noredirect=1#comment136700_76907) and the similar abbreviations and descriptions in the chart on the [page](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/Spectrpy/InfraRed/infrared.htm) linked by Tyberius in his [comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76907/what-does-s-m-w-m-w-w-s-mean-in-the-context-of-infrared-spectroscopy?noredirect=1#comment136717_76907), the meanings appear to be:

- `s`trong
- `m`oderate (or `m`edium)
- `w`eak

Notations such as `m-w` and `w-s` presumably indicate a peak intensity that is variable in the indicated range, depending on the properties of the particular molecule of interest.